# Is there a trigonal nonsingular non-hyperelliptic genus $5$ curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is there a trigonal nonsingular non-hyperelliptic genus $5$ curve?

My attempt: No. A nonsingular non-hyperelliptic genus $5$ curve is a complete intersection of three quadric surfaces and by Enriques-Babbage a curve cannot be a complete intersection and be trigonal. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you know that every nonsingular, non-hyperelliptic genus 5 curve is a complete intersection of three quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^4$?

Comment: @Daniel Hast We have $\deg (\omega_C) = 8$ and hence $H^0(C,\mathcal{O}_{C}(2)) = 12$ and $H^0(\mathbb{P}^4,\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^4}(2)) = 15$. Thus there are three linearly independent quadric surfaces containing $C$. As the dimension of their intersection is $1$, the intersection must be equal to the curve $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a cubic scroll $S \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ and its ruling $L \subset S$. For a general cubic hypersurface $Z \subset \mathbb{P}^4$ containing $L$ we have
$$
Z \cap S = L \cup C,
$$
where $C$ is a smooth curve of degree 8. It is easy to check that the hyperplane class of $\mathbb{P}^4$ restricts to the canonical class of $C$, hence $C$ is not hyperelliptic. As its degree is 8, its genus is 5. On the other hand, the projection of the scroll $S \to \mathbb{P}^1$ induces on $C$ a trigonal structure.

Comment: OK I know what genus 5 means in topology, I know it means it has 5 "holes" ... but everything else makes 0 sense to me. Is this stuff useful? I find it hard to motivate learning a billion definitions. What problems can be solved with these ideas?

Comment: @Sasha What is a (cubic) scroll? I am going through Hartshorne and have not come across it yet.

Comment: Also, why does this not pose a contradiction to Ex. 5.5 in Hartshorne's Chapter IV? There it is stated (and I thought, I had a proof, if it helps, I'll copy it into the comment) that: A non-hyperelliptic curve of genus $5$ has a $g^1_3$ iff it can be represented as a plane quintic with one node.

Comment: @maths_student: A cubic scroll is the image of the blowup of $\mathbb{P}^2$ in a point embedded by the complete linear system $|2\ell - e|$ of conics on the plane passing through the point (its rulings are the images of lines through the point). If you take the strict transform in such a blowup of a plane quintic singular at the point, its image in $\mathbb{P}^4$ will have the form I described, so my description is consistent with Hartshorne.

Comment: Thank you, Sasha!